# Can we store an object of a record in Sugar ORM Table to another Sugar ORM Table?

Tags: android, database, orm

I am trying out the Sugar ORM to make a small app that works like a small shopping center.
I just need to store an object of a Sugar ORM record table to another table.
I have tried a lot but it says 'Null Pointer Exception on envoking virtual method:'----------' on a null object reference'...
when I tried to retrieve a single object stored to call a return method.

Comment: Hi Sujal, and welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you share the code which is throwing this error?

Comment: class Items extends SugarRecord implements Serializable{//Default Constructed,My Constructer,properties, Getters & Setters}

Comment: class Cart extends SugarRecord{Items item;String user;//Same as above}

Comment: I got success in adding item object to a Cart record but when I tries to retrieve it then a null pointer exception crashed the app.

Comment: I have tried another way to achieve my goal but it would be good for me if I can know the reason behind the exception.